# js not available for ajax appeared elements in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, coffeescript, ruby-on-rails-5, turbolinks

For example, I have a form field which appears with ajax request, it has class `can_be_deleted`.

```
<div class="form-group">
  <%= f.text_field :name %>
  <%= f.hidden_field :_destroy %>
  <span class="fa fa-close can_be_deleted"></span>
</div>
```

In the same time I have some already existing elements which appear with page load, they also have class `can_be_deleted`.

```
<div class="form-group article_tag">
  <%= f.object.name %>
  <%= f.hidden_field :slug %>
  <%= f.hidden_field :name %>
  <%= f.hidden_field :_destroy %>
  <span class="fa fa-close can_be_deleted"></span>
</div>
```

The coffescript which is binding when an element with this class is pressed, works for all elements EXCEPT created by ajax.

```
jQuery ($) ->
  $(document).on "turbolinks:load", ->    
    $(".can_be_deleted").click ->
      console.log("clicked")
```

How to make it working with all elements? Strange situation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `ajaxComplete` event, try this:

```
$(document).on "turbolinks:load ajaxComplete", ->
```

instead this:

```
$(document).on "turbolinks:load", ->
```